# How to create AdSense account for different websites with different owners/payees?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I'm trying to understand how does the AdSense system work. I've looked in the AdSense Help, forums and asked people I know. But still, I'm very confused.

I'd like to be able to set an account for a website owner. While not breaking the rules and policies of the AdSense account. 
Here is what I find hard to understand:
While setting up an account you have to connect it to your site (example.com), this is fine as this is my main site.
From what I understand this creates an AdSense account - there must be 1 AdSense account per website (not sure if I'm correct).
Now, I've also added the website under the "Sites" tab on the AdSense console and pasted the code given in the header of the website.
This completes the first step, which I assumes is correct and meets the rules and policies of the AdSense account.

The next thing I would like to do is set up a new account  for a new site. For this site I'd like set a different Gmail as the owner (he will be receiving the pay-out), but also be able to allow me to edit/create new ads for him as he has zero interest in doing it himself.

One solution, I guess, is to create the account on his Gmail, using his credentials, which seems a bit off. Because then I would have to enter his password each time I connect to the AdSense account. Assuming I might have more sites that I'm managing their AdSense, I would have all of their passwords and would have to connect to each account at a time. Not very efficient. I might be able to invite myself to his account after I create the account on his behalf. But I'm not sure If this is allowed? As I would have two different AdSense accounts containing the same email address (although not the actual owner of two different account/sites).

Another solution I am looking in to is creating another site on the original account - through the "Sites" tab. This will let me mange the ads on the site without needing the owner's Gmail credentials. The problem is - How will I be able to redirect the ad revenue to him? I assume the earnings will be gathered under the same account (my account). Also, does registering his Gmail account on the same domain (that I added to my sites) will now create a new problem? Would this be considered as having two owners registered on the same website? even though the payee details are correct (and different).

I am really struggling to understand this issue and have not found any credible source, or at least a clear one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
If there is any other way of doing this, or something similar I am open to hear and learn about it. I really don't want to accidentally cross any lines and am trying to figure out the right way of doing this.
Thank you in advance for anyone helping me :).

Answer (score 1):

You can create Adsense account for different Websites but you can't create a single account that pays different payees for different Websites in a single account.

Because Adsense allows the website to which you're the owner, if you want different payees for different Websites you might have to create another accounts for those Websites.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense accounts and sites are not one to one.  You can have a single AdSense account that shows ads on multiple sites.    Although it isn't common, you could also have multiple AdSense accounts showing ads on different pages of a single site.

There is however only a single payee for each AdSense account.  The account needs to be created for the person that is going to get the money.  Your client needs to have their own AdSense account.  They can apply for it with their site.

Once the account has been created, they can add you as a manager of their AdSense account. See [Add a user to your account - AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2659101?hl=en):

> To give access to your account:
>
> 1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
> 2. Click Account.
> 3. Click Access and authorization, then click User management.
> 4. In the field provided, enter the email address of the user you want to share your account with, then click Invite.
> 5. The user is added to the “Users with sign-in access” table with the status “pending.”
> 6. Once the user has accepted your email invitation by clicking the link in the email and associating their Google Account with the AdSense account listed in the invitation, their “pending” status will disappear from the “Users with sign-in access” table.
>      Whilst you can’t assign an access level to a user in the email, you can [change a user’s access level](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2659103) at any time.

Once you have been given access to the AdSense account, you can manage the ads for that user without having to log in to their account.   They will receive all payments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Will there be any issue if my Gmail is associated with several Adsense accounts (each having a different payee - not me)?

Comment: Each AdSense account needs have a different Google account owner.  Each Google account can only be associated with one gmail address.